# Empty Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays

```
int main(){

int rem, N, dig, i;

printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &N);

while (N > 0){
    N /= 10;
    dig += 1;
}

int D[dig] = {0};
```

So I'm writing a program where a person enters a number (ex. 276433) and I must count the number of times a number appears (but that's not what I need help with), Since a person can enter a number of any size i used the while loop to count the numbers in the number entered, in order to initialize the size of my array D[], however I get an error? Is it not possible to declare an array in the middle or am I approaching this problem with wrong thinking? Thank you. The language is C by the way.

Comment: btw the warning I receive is "warning: excess elements in array internalizer"

Comment: This is called a variable length array, and some versions of the C standard forbid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking the compiler to declare an automatic variable that is an array of a size unknown when the compiler creates this code as you didn't initialize the 'dig' value. Instead you should be using malloc to dynamically allocate the array for the size required at runtime. So:

```
int *D = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * dig);
...
D[0] = 1; /* for instance */
```

If we compile your example with gcc we get slightly more information about the problem:

```
z.c: In function ‘main’:
z.c:5:3: error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
   int D[dig] = {0};
   ^
z.c:5:3: warning: excess elements in array initializer [enabled by default]
z.c:5:3: warning: (near initialization for ‘D’) [enabled by default]
z.c:5:7: warning: unused variable ‘D’ [-Wunused-variable]
   int D[dig] = {0};
       ^
```

The above points out that the compiler doesn't know to create your array for the variable size you are providing. Given the size is unknown, it follows that the initialization cannot be the correct number of elements.

Answer (score 1):

you have to write

```
  int D[dig];
```

without

```
  ={0}
```

and it will work;

This is the only way to allocate an array with a variable integer without malloc !

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot declare a statically allocated array with a dynamic size. Static allocation is evaluated at compile time, and the compiler has no way of knowing what the value going into array size will be.

You can either define a fixed buffer size and ensure the input doesn't exceed it, or use the following:

```
 int *array;
 array=(int *) malloc(size*sizeof(int));
```

where `size` is the size you want the array to be. (code snippet taken from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/416/))

Answer (score 0):

The array initializer can only be used for constant size arrays. Instead you need to do something like:

```
int D[dig];
if (dig > 0)
    D[0] = 0;
```

This becomes a run time assignment and is ok.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, the variables that you do not initialize (that you do not set an initial value to), do not get defaulted to `0`, unless they are declared outside of the functions, within the file-scope.

Maybe not the `N`, but you should at least initialize the `dig` with `0`. It is never bad to initialize variables upon declaration, so you may just initialize all of them.

```
int     rem = 0,
        N = 0,
        dig = 0,    // <-- especially this
        i = 0;
```

If you are using a compiler that follows the C99 standard, you should be able to declare Variable Length Arrays. However, you may not initialize Variable Length Arrays, no matter where you declare them. You can simply rather:

```
#include <string.h>

...

    int D[dig];
    memset( D, 0, sizeof D );
```

To achieve what you want to achieve there. But you do not need all this anyway. You've said that you'll make something to count the number of occurrence of digits. All you need is an array of `10` members, one for each digit from `0` to `9`. So you can declare your `D` as `int D[10] = { 0 };` above all else.